# Replacing german umlauts generated by latex or bibtex tool in java?

Tags: java, bibtex

I want to replace the german umlauts generated by a Citavi-Bibtex-Export-Tool. For example one reference string input is `J{\"o}rg`and I want `Jörg` as a result. After inspecting my JUnit-Test the result of my method was `J{"o}rg` - what went wrong?

```
public String replaceBibtexMutatedVowels(String str){
    CharSequence target = "{\\\"o}";
    CharSequence replacement = "ö";
    str.replace(target, replacement);
    return str;
}
```

UPDATE: Thanks guys - I was able to master german umlauts - unfortunately Bibtex escapes quotation marks with `{\dg}` - I was not able to create the corresponding java code.

```
    String afterDg = "";
    CharSequence targetDg = "{\\dg}";
    CharSequence replacementDg = "\"";
    afterDg = afterAe.replace(targetDg, replacementDg);
    newStringInstance = afterDg;
    return newStringInstance;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you are doing all right, but:

```
 str.replace(target, replacement);
```

must be replaced with

```
 str = str.replace(target, replacement);
```

because replace doesn't change the string itself, but returns a "replaced string".

P.S.: German has more special characters than "ö"; you're missing "ä", "ü" (and their corresponding capital letters), "ß" etc.

And here's my test code:

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String latexText = "J{\\\"o}rg";
        String normalText = replaceBibtexMutatedVowels(latexText);
        System.out.println(latexText);
        System.out.println(normalText);
    }

    public static String replaceBibtexMutatedVowels(String str) {
        CharSequence target = "{\\\"o}";
        CharSequence replacement = "ö";
        str = str.replace(target, replacement);
        return str;
    }

}
```

Comment: great adivce - unfortunately there is another problem to get it done if bibtex quotation marks are showing up.

Comment: Do you mean something like text = "\"``Some quotation\'\'\""?